# Converting time to date

Tags: php

I have a script

```
   idea_slug=$_POST['idea_slug'];
   $data['idea_date']=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM td_idea WHERE idea_slug='$idea_slug'")->result_array();
   $submit_date=$data['idea_date'][0]['idea_submit_date'];

   $datetime1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $submit_date);
   $submit_date= $datetime1->format('Y-m-d');

   $submit_date = strtotime($submit_date);

   $end = strtotime('+90 days', $submit_date);
```

now i want to convert $end to Y/m/d format
how can i do so??

Comment: Why are you creating a DateTime object, and then converting it to a unix timestamp - makes no sense at all (and it's the second time I've seen it today)

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

```
echo date('Y/m/d', $end);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) "alternative" to [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime) is [modify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can do like following

```
$date_format = date('Y/m/d', $end);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$datetime1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $submit_date);
$end = clone $datetime1;
$end->add(new DateInterval('P90D'));
echo $end->format('Y/m/d');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simpel =), you should check the DateTime class

```
$datetime1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $submit_date);
$datetime1->modify('+90 day');
$end = $datetime1->format('d/m/Y');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Cheers